# How to custom format a negative percent as (x.xx%)

Tags: excel

I'm using the following code:

```
#.#0%;[Red](#.#0%)
```

However, for negative decimal numbers i'm getting:

```
(.32%)
```

When I try to modify the code to:

```
#.#0%;[Red](0#.#0%)
```

This works in the above example and outputs:

```
(0.32%)
```

But for something like -1.55% it outputs:

```
(01.55%)
```

Any solution to get the leading zero in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `0` just before the `.`:

```
0.#0%;[Red](0.#0%)
```

[image]